# Java2D collision doesn't work with tile size properly

Tags: java, dictionary, 2d

I've made a simple collision with my tiled map in my 2d game, but it looks like the collision doesn't look at the player's height or the size of the tiles, I mean, if I walk from the left to the right side, it some what will work, so is top to bottom, but if I walk from right to left or bottom to top, it will only detect the other tile at the center of the place which is incorrect.

The following gif will show an example of left to right & top to bottom which works:

By the way: 0 = sand 1 = lava (red), see the println on the left side bottom!!

[image: img]

And the following one will show the right to left, which doesnt work so you can see:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/8ea3df0f2c1961f9ae756611c8ac9e0e.gif))</sub>

I am not really sure why does this happen, this is how I detect tiles in current region:

```
    int[][] mapData = map.getMap();
    System.out.println(mapData[p.getY() / 30][p.getX() / 30]);
```

And this is how I get map from the .txt file:

```
public void buildTile() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.tileMap));
        this.tileWidth = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        this.tileHeight = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        map = new int[this.tileHeight][this.tileWidth];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.tileHeight; i++) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            String[] chars = line.split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < this.tileWidth; j++) {
                if (j >= chars.length) {
                    reader.close();
                    return;
                }
                map[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(chars[j]);
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But mostly, the problem is probably with the drawing method, because we cant really know that a tile is 30x30, I am not sure, but this is my draw map method:

```
private void renderMap(Graphics2D g) throws IOException {
    Player p1 = this.game.getPlayer();
    int[][] tiledMap = this.map.getMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.map.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.map.getWidth(); j++) {
            int currentRow = tiledMap[i][j];            
            if (currentRow == 0) {
                g.drawImage(Collusion.getTile(currentRow), (j * 30) + p1.getOffX(), (i * 30) + p1.getOffY(), null);
            }               
            if (currentRow == 1) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect((j * 30) + p1.getOffX(), (i * 30) + p1.getOffY(), 30, 30);
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Why does it do that? let me know if you need more pieces of code to detect the problem.
Maybe I need a better way of reading / drawing the maps?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like detection is occurring when the lower right corner of your figure connects with the square. Check your collision detection to make sure it checks every corner of the character rather than a single point. 
I can't tell you more unless you post code related to th collision.